# react-table Editable content + sorting; editable cell doesn't update?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

When modifying data in one column that will effect the sort order, the data re-sorts correctly, but the input used does not update to the new rows data.

It's simplest to reproduce here https://codesandbox.io/s/kky34kkwr

1. Enter 99 into col 2 "age", row 3
2. Press tab
3. Note the top row is now the row we edited, age=99, full=198

What we should see here is the row we entered `99` into moving to the top of the table (as it does), and the new row replacing the row we edited's previous position should have the data associated with that new row (not `99`).

I can't seem to find a way to force this to update, or even a janky hack to achieve what I want in inadvisable ways. Hoping someone can help!

EDIT: This image shows the display immediately after step 2 of the above instructions.
[image: Row 3 still has 99 in the 2nd column]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone struggling with this, while we wait for a fix I've found a workaround.

Given the example in the original question, replacing `renderEditable` with the following will act correctly:

```
renderEditable(cellInfo) {
  return (
    <div
      style={{ backgroundColor: "#fafafa" }}
      contentEditable
      suppressContentEditableWarning
      onBlur={e => {
        const data = [...this.state.data];
        data[cellInfo.index][cellInfo.column.id] = e.target.innerHTML;
        data[cellInfo.index].full = data[cellInfo.index].age * 2;
        e.target.innerHTML = this.state.data[cellInfo.index][cellInfo.column.id];
        this.setState({ data });
      }}
    >{this.state.data[cellInfo.index][cellInfo.column.id]}</div>
  );
}
```

The `onBlur` event fires before the table re-sorts itself, so if we just grab the value, put it aside, and reset the `innerHTML` to the original value before triggering the resort with `setState` we end up with correct values displayed. It's not ideal but it works. Don't forget to validate the input.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are `hot-calculating` the value `full` of your table and sorting your table on the basis of this `full` attribute. To solve your problem, you can

1) Not sort your table according to `full`.

like this

```
defaultSorted={[
  {
    id: "firstName",
    desc: true
  }
]}
```

2) Avoid hot-calculating your `full`, and calculate it only once in your constructor.

Something like this

```
this.state = {
  data: makeData().map(item => ({ ...item, full: item.age * 2 }))
};
```

and your header like this

```
{
  Header: "full",
  id: "full",
  accessor: "full",
}
```

Comment: I've updated the codesandbox to reflect what you suggest, it better highlights the problem this way. Of course simply not sorting will avoid the problem (or not allowing data to be edited), but it doesn't address it, and sadly the use-case requires sorting on a calculated column.

Comment: I am not clear on what you actually require ! Say I edit the third row -> That should change both age as well as full, yes ? If both change, it will resort itself so that the thing we just edited goes to the very top of the table. Everything else remains in the same order in this case. Except for the row we edited off course. So what is the actual requirement that you need ?

Comment: Yes that's correct, it re-sorts correctly, but the input you typed in does not update to contain the data passed in the `value` prop. So we end up with the first row having `age=99` AND the third row `age` cell displaying `99` still, when it *should* have the data from the new record that is now occupying the third place in the order.

Comment: Seems like there is a bug with editable react table when used with default sorting. You can report this to the developers in Git

Comment: Yeah, raised an issue a while ago https://github.com/react-tools/react-table/issues/1096 - Was hoping someone may have a clever way to brute force update it or some sort of workaround. Thanks for trying!